# PerfectTemplate got "Fatal error: UnsafeMutablePointer.initialize overlapping range" under Relase Mode

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, perfect, unsafemutablepointer

I followed the instructions of "Getting Started with Perfect"(https://perfect.org/docs/gettingStarted.html)

```
git clone https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/PerfectTemplate.git
cd PerfectTemplate
swift build
.build/debug/PerfectTemplate
swift package generate-xcodeproj
```

to create an Xcode project on macOS(10.15.7). Then, I opened this project with Xcode(11.7) and chose "Building for Profiling". After launching PerfectTemplate by double clicking /PerfectTemplate/Build/Products/Release/PerfectTemplate, I sent a GET request to

http://localhost:8181/a12345678901234567890

Then I got

```
[INFO] Starting HTTP server localhost on :::8181
Fatal error: UnsafeMutablePointer.initialize overlapping range: file /AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-1103.8.25.8/swift/stdlib/public/core/UnsafePointer.swift, line 832
Illegal instruction: 4
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
```

It's easy to crash the application by sending a long path url. I can't reproduce this issue under Debug Mode. Did anyone meet the same issue??

Perfect is a good toolkit to develop a server app on macOS, but I'm worried about this unpredictable memory issue. I hope I just did something wrong.